# Make 'export to excel' button in DataTable for Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to ask if someone know about 'export to excel' button in Laravel. I need to use the button inside the DataTable beside 'export pdf' button. Can someone help me to make the button function properly.

First pic is the controller for 'export' [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8TKV.png)

```
if(!empty($request['export']))
        {
            return Excel::download(new ExcelExport($start_date, $end_date, $staff_name), 'Laporan Pegawai Tidak Aktif.xls');
        }
```

Sec pic is the blade for DataTable script [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOBfl.png)

```
$(function () {
  $('#staffs').DataTable({
     dom: 
         "<'row'<'col-sm-5'l><'col-sm-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
         "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",

         buttons: [{
           extend : 'pdfHtml5',
           text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Export PDF',
           className: 'btn btn-default',
           title: "Senarai Pegawai Tidak Aktif",
           exportOptions: 
           {
              columns: ':visible:not(.not-exported)'
           },
   },

         {
           extend : 'excelHtml5',
           text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export Excel',
           className: 'btn btn-default',
           name:'export',
           text: function (dt) 
           {
              return '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> ' + ('buttons.excel', 'Export Excel');
           },

              action: function (e, dt, button, config) 
              {
                 var url = dt.ajax.url() || window.location.href;
                 var params = _buildParams(dt, 'excel');

                _downloadFromUrl(url, params);
              }
         }
       ],
```

*help me to check whether the code for export excel is right or not

Comment: Please share code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see an example of how to add export button in datatable then this link is the right place for you.

[Larave Yajra DataTables](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-yajra-datatables-export-to-excel-csv-button-exampleexample.html)